# What is the file structure of wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I've done some searching and I couldn't find anything, I'm looking for the file structure of wordpress for example: wp-admin would contain bla2 (with explanations of what the files would do)...

FYI I'm now looking to edit the pages' code, not just the themes' code. But I wanna know what each of the files do(well not that specific), cause I'm greedy. Please ignore the last part...

Comment: bad idea. you should really write a plugin.

Comment: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: @DanielA.White Ok, I'll take a look at it later

Comment: @RQDQ I'm looking for a link for it, I must have missed it in the codex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm looking for a link for it, I must have missed it in the codex

http://codex.wordpress.org/Site_Architecture_1.5